# Array key variable is changing but not the variable data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, gallery

I am trying to make a very simple image gallery viewer and something is not working properly with my array and its data, more so the page doesn't respond to the array key changing.  What I want is when the `next-button` or `previous-button` is clicked, the variable that is in the key changes along with the information that is displayed on the page.  Here is my code

HTML

```
<div id="gallery">
  <div id="gallery-control-bar">
    <div id="gallery-buttons" class="control-bar-item">
      <div id="previous-button" class="gallery-button">&larr;</div>
      <div id="next-button" class="gallery-button">&rarr;</div>
    </div><!-- "#gallery-buttons" -->
    <div id="image-index" class="control-bar-item">
      <span id="current-post">1</span> of <span id="post-total">29</span>
    </div><!-- "#image-index" -->
    <div id="gallery-type" class="control-bar-item">
      <img id="gallery-switch" alt="Gallery Icon" src="images/gallery-icon.png">
    </div>
  </div><!-- "#gallery-control-bar" -->

  <div id="gallery-image"></div>
</div><!-- "#gallery" -->
```

JS (this is where I think the problem lies)

```
var currentImg = 0;
var totalImg = js_p_id.length - 1;

var userCurrent = currentImg + 1;
var userTotal = js_p_id.length;

$("#next-button").click(function() {
    if (currentImg == totalImg) {
        currentImg = 0;
    }
    else {
        currentImg++;
    }
    return;
});

$("#previous-button").click(function() {
    if (currentImg == 0) {
        currentImg = totalImg;
    }
    else {
        currentImg--;
    }
    return;
});

$("#gallery-image").html("<img src='" + js_p_src[currentImg] + "'>");
$("#gallery-title").html(js_p_title[currentImg]);
$("#gallery-medium").html(js_p_medium[currentImg]);
$("#gallery-size").html(js_p_size[currentImg]);
$("#gallery-date").html(js_p_date[currentImg]);

$("#current-post").html(userCurrent);
$("#post-total").html(userTotal);
```

The variables with the `js` prefix are arrays that have been converted over to JS from PHP with JSON in another script, those are working fine and have no problem.  Technically, the image and its information should be switching each time I click the previous and next buttons but don't.  I put an alert on all of the variables and they all change as I press the buttons but the image/info on the page stays the same.  What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Where is the code that changes the _DOM_ after `currentImg` has been modified?

Comment: @PaulS. I guess I don't have any?  Is this my problem?

Comment: most likely. As it is, it looks like you modify `currentImg` in a click event, but then do nothing with it.

Comment: @PaulS. should I include the `html()` functions within the click event functions then?  Would that do the trick?

Comment: I would actually wrap them in a third _function_ and invoke that just before the `return;` in both the previous _functions_. This would also mean you can invoke it straight away for the initial page, and you don't have too much code duplication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("#gallery-image").html("<img src='" + js_p_src[currentImg] + "'>");
```

This needs to be inside the two paging functions.

You are incrementing/decrimenting the currentImg variable, but you are not then setting the image after that each time.

EDIT: Or in it's own function, then just call it from the other two.
EDIT2: They all need to go in there.

```
function changeImg(){
    $("#gallery-image").html("<img src='" + js_p_src[currentImg] + "'>");
    $("#gallery-title").html(js_p_title[currentImg]);
    $("#gallery-medium").html(js_p_medium[currentImg]);
    $("#gallery-size").html(js_p_size[currentImg]);
    $("#gallery-date").html(js_p_date[currentImg]);
}
```